# UIGraphicsImageRenderer: iosurface is too large for GPU

Tags: ios, swift, metal, uigraphicsimagerenderer, iosurface

I use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` to draw a large image, but the Xcode logging `Metal API Validation Enabled` and `[Metal] 5073 by 8663 iosurface is too large for GPU`. The resulting image is a blank image with a very small size.

```swift
let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
format.scale = 1            

renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: borderSize, format: format)
let newImage = renderer.image { context in    
  image.draw(in: imageRect)    
  …
}
```

My purpose is to add a border with text to the image, is there a way to solve this problem? Or is there any other way of drawing large image?

Comment: What is your image size?

Comment: @HamidYusifli 5073 x 8068, shot on a camera.